# Quarkus mongodb panache with multiple clients not working

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm using quarkus panache to access mongodb in my project. I need to connect to two different clusters and so I need to have different connection-string. This is what I'm doing right now

application.yaml

```
quarkus:
  mongodb:
    db1:
      connection-string: ${DB1_MONGODB_URI}
      database: ${DB1_MONGODB_DB}
    db2:
      connection-string: ${DB2_MONGODB_URI}
      database: ${DB2_MONGODB_DB}
```

First entity

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "log", clientName = "db1")
public class Log extends PanacheMongoEntityBase {
    @BsonId
    public ObjectId id;
    public LogType type;
    public String message;
    public Instant createdOn;
}
```

Second entity

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "order", clientName = "db2")
public class Order extends PanacheMongoEntityBase {
    @BsonId
    public ObjectId id;
    public BigDecimal total;
    public BigDecimal subtotal;
    ...
}
```

The problem arises when I try to call the persist(); method on one of these entities. I receive the error:

> 2023-11-15 11:31:11,268 ERROR [com.test.resource.Resource] (executor-thread-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find MongoClient bean for entity @io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.MongoEntity(readPreference="", database="", collection="log", clientName="db1")
> at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.runtime.BeanUtils.clientFromArc(BeanUtils.java:58)
> at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.runtime.MongoOperations.mongoDatabase(MongoOperations.java:395)
> at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.runtime.MongoOperations.mongoCollection(MongoOperations.java:193)
> at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.runtime.MongoOperations.mongoCollection(MongoOperations.java:391)
> at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.common.runtime.MongoOperations.persist(MongoOperations.java:73)
> at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.PanacheMongoEntityBase.persist(PanacheMongoEntityBase.java:36)

I cannot find anything online and I don't know what to do.
If I remove the double connections and work with entities without the clientName in the annotation everything works perfectly.

**Edit**

I have found the cause of the issue but I have no idea on how to solve it.
The problem seems to arise when I use also the reactive client with the @MongoClientName annotation. Something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FirstRepository {

    @Inject
    @MongoClientName("db1")
    ReactiveMongoClient client;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.mongodb.db1.database")
    String databaseName;

    public boolean existsOrder(ObjectId id) {
        return getCollection("order")
                .countDocuments(
                        Filters.eq("_id", id)

                )
                .await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(15)) > 0;
    }

    private ReactiveMongoCollection<Document> getCollection(String collectionName) {
        return client.getDatabase(databaseName).getCollection(collectionName);
    }
}
```

If I have also this class in the project and I try to call the persist(); method of the entity annotated with the clientName that is also used for the ReactiveMongoClient than I receive that error.

Comment: Hi,
I cannot see anything wrong with your example. If you can create a small reproducer project I can have a look.

Comment: I created a new project by coping the two entities, the entire pom.xml and the application.yaml using the same two connections and it works. I don't understand why it does not work in my regular project.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem and I edited the question.  You can download a reproducer here https://file.io/Fmohi0hRqvY3